# .Net Core website - Bad Gateway (Connection Error)

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a website targetting `.NetCoreApp 1.1` it runs fine locally but does not work deployed I get the completely useless error message:

> "502.3 Bad gateway. There was a connection error while trying to route
>   the request."

The event viewer says `"Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYAPP' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\MyApp' created process with command line '"dotnet" .\Web.dll' but failed to listen on port XXXX"`

There is nothing useful in .net core logs folder except that the application started and is listening.

On the server I have installed:

- Microsoft .Net core 1.1.1 -Runtime (x64)
- Microsoft .Net core 1.1.2 -Runtime (x64)
- Microsoft .Net core 1.0.5 & 1.1.2 - Windows Server Hosting
- Microsoft Http Platform Handler 1.2

I am using Web Deploy to deploy it. I have checked the directory structure. I have disabled the start up error page. It is running in it's own app pool which has access to the file system. CLR version is changed to No Managed Code. Load User Profile set to True.

My program class is as follows:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
#if !DEBUG
    // Disable windows auth for local debug
    .UseWebListener(options =>
        {
        options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
        options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
        })
#endif
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseApplicationInsights()
    .Build();
```

Edit: Executing dotnet MyApp.dll in the deployment directory tells me it is listening on port 5000. I can access this locally and the site is now running fine so it appears to be the IIS integration.

How do I get debug information to work out what is wrong? Or better yet, what is wrong?

UPDATE: It may be that Kestrel is being blocked by an anti-virus system when it is trying to use IIS as a reverse proxy. I've not been able to verify this yet.

Answer (score 0):

One could be thinking that your ASP.NET Core app is configured to listen on a port on which another is already listening. Can you check that using https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx for instance?

Comment: Every time I hit the website it says it is listening on a different port in the event viewer. Is this what you mean? Or do you mean the IIS port?

Comment: I tried IIS setting to 2 different ports and still the same error message

Comment: So, your port changing makes sense (I tried on my end) because IIS is acting like a reverse proxy, listening on a port X and then instanciating your .NET CORE application telling it on which port it should be listening to (it's a  parameter of the cmd line I believe). What I would suggest is to try to launch your application from it's folder with a dotnet run to see if in that case, it can listen to the port, removing IIS from the equation for the moment.

Comment: dotnet Web.dll works and I can hit it on the listening port :) What next?

Comment: On that, I can't help much, because I'm compiling against the full framework so I get an .exe directly, but I'm quite sure you should be able to run your .NET Core app separatly and that should give you precious information. You've tried in the folder where it's getting deployed? It should work according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run

Comment: Yes it does work. Just not in IIS where I need it to where I get a useless error message. Thanks anyway. Feels like I am moving forward

Comment: Ok, let's keep digging then ... when you launch it this way with dotnet run, it launches a Kestrel web server that must be listening always on the same port (5000 by default), you should be able to see it in the console, right? I see two options here, 1/ IIS is asking to Kestrel to listen on a port it is not allowed to (system configuration? firewall?) OR 2/IIS is instanciating your ASP.NET Core app with a user account that doesn't have enough rights to do what it needs.

Comment: To test 1/ you could be trying to force kestrel to listen to a port that was previously failing (somewhere in program.cs, near UseUrls) To test 2/ check under which identity IIS is launching the process dotnet when failing using your task manager

Comment: dotnet doesn't appear long enough in Task Manager and in any case Task Manager doesn't indicate who the user is. It is a 'Background process'

Comment: yes it does if you click on "show processes from all users", I mean it can depends on your version of Windows or whatever, but I can definitively see all my process. Something else you could try: your ASP.NET Core app runs inside an application in IIS, which is using an application pool (with "No managed Code" if configured properly). Change the identity of this application pool to an admin user to see if it helps (as a test of course, you cannot give your app that much credentials).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148066/discussion-between-johnstaveley-and-daboul).

Answer (score 0):

**Missing .NET Framework version**

**Browser**: 502.3 Bad Gateway - There was a connection error while trying to route the request.
**Application Log**: ErrorCode = Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MY_APPLICATION' with physical root 'C:{PATH}\' failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\my_application.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008081.

**ASP.NET Core Module Log**: Missing method, file, or assembly exception. The method, file, or assembly specified in the exception is a .NET Framework method, file, or assembly.

Troubleshooting:
Install the .NET Framework version missing from the system.
For a framework-dependent deployment, confirm that you have the correct runtime installed on the system. For example if you upgrade a project from 1.0 to 1.1, deploy to the hosting system, and receive this exception, ensure you install the 1.1 framework on the hosting system.

Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#common-errors) for more information

**For Debugging IIS And Other Server Errors in asp.net core**

Open web.config
change `stdoutLogEnabled="true"`

In the publish directory make a logs folder

Comment: What am I missing, you can see above what I have installed and what I am using?

Comment: Go to IIS Server check modules.If AspNetCoreModule exist

Comment: Yes, AspNetCoreModule exists